# SQL Server 2014 - exec procedure with 2 datasets

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a procedure that returns 2 datasets. I need to exec the procedure once and insert both datasets into two temp tables. Is that possible and if so then how?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Test 
AS
    SELECT 
        Country = 'Germany', City = 'Berlin', Qty = 10

    SELECT 
        Id = 5, Color = 'Red'
```

Something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp1 (Country VARCHAR(MAX), City VARCHAR(MAX), Qty INT)
CREATE TABLE #tmp2 (Id INT, Color VARCHAR(MAX))

INSERT INTO #tmp1
INSERT INTO #tmp2
    EXEC Test
```

Regards,
Przemek

Comment: No.  In SQL Server, only the last data set is inserted into a table.  You should really think about using stored functions or another mechanism for returning values.

Comment: Thank you Gordon.

Comment: Note the description of the `procedure` tag says "Do not use this tag for stored procedures, Use `stored-procedures` tag instead."